# Is it possible to setup ADFS 3.0 as service provider and to accept incoming claims from other federations.?

Tags: php, codeigniter, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs3.0

Is it possible to setup  ADFS 3.0 as service provider and to accept incoming claims from other federations.?

For ex: I have configured, ADFS in my window 2012 R2 Server. Client is having Ping Identity. How to make this combination to work.

Using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is PHP, then it would be easier to connect your application to simpleSAMLphp. This handles all the SAML protocol issues for you.

Then your path could be:

Application --> simpleSAMLphp --> ADFS --> Ping Identity.

Or you could leave out ADFS and go direct. This would depend on your use case.

Comment: Am very new to SSO, Is there any example project available to connect Application --> simpleSAMLphp --> ADFS. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Probably not since it's two projects. The simpleSAMLphp documentation shows how to hook up an application and then federate - http://www.lewisroberts.com/2015/09/06/integrating-simplesamlphp-with-adfs-2012r2/

Answer (score 0):

yes, ADFS can be a Service provider and/or an Identity Provider.